# is the common Makefile idiom "> $@" (redirecting output to the target) wrong?

Tags: makefile

It is hard to believe, but it seems to me that the common Makefile idiom "> $@" is wrong.  In particular, a target whose rule has a command that fails but uses this redirection will fail the first time around but not subsequent times.  This is because even though the command fails, the redirection "succeeds" in the sense of creating an up-to-date (albeit zero-length) target.

It seems to me that the correct thing to do is to redirect to a temporary and on success rename this temporary to the target.

Here's and example Makefile:

```
bad-target:
        command-that-will-fail > $@

good-target:
        command-that-will-fail > $@.tmp || ( rm $@.tmp; false )
        mv $@.tmp $@

clean:
        rm -f bad-target good-target
```

And here's a sequence of commands illustrating the problem and its solution:

```
$ make clean
rm -f bad-target good-target

$ make bad-target
command-that-will-fail > bad-target  
/bin/sh: command-that-will-fail: not found  
make: *** [bad-target] Error 127

$ make bad-target
make: `bad-target' is up to date.

$ make good-target
command-that-will-fail > good-target.tmp || ( rm good-target.tmp; false )  
/bin/sh: command-that-will-fail: not found  
make: *** [good-target] Error 1

$ make good-target
command-that-will-fail > good-target.tmp || ( rm good-target.tmp; false )  
/bin/sh: command-that-will-fail: not found  
make: *** [good-target] Error 1
```

Answer (score 22):

If you're using GNU make, you may also add the `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` special target to your makefile.  This will cause make to delete the output file if there is an error during execution of the commands for that file:

```
all: foo.o

foo.o:
        echo bogus! > $@
        exit 1

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
```

Here's an example of this makefile in action:

```
$ gmake
echo bogus! > foo.o
exit 1
gmake: *** [foo.o] Error 1
gmake: *** Deleting file `foo.o'
```

This is easier to use than your version, since you need not modify every rule in the makefile.

Comment: Is there any way to get DELETE_ON_ERROR behavior only for specific rules?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is an obvious solution, but many common commands provide a -o  flag or similar. So instead of output redirection, you should use the rule:

```
target: target.dep
    some_command target.dep -o $@
```

If the command fails, the output file will not be created. I haven't had many occasions to use output redirection in makefiles.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is definitely something to bear in mind.

But sometimes you're OK with the command failing and you don't want to retry it, because the error would only repeat itself.

In that case leaving an empty result is OK.  Just don't make subsequent processing count on there being meaningful content in that file.